# Is there a way to extract the number from this data frame in R? Extracting integer from chr string

Tags: r, integer, extract

SO i have the following data frame

[image]

I tried using gsub to extract the data but it doesn't work because it seem gsub only extracting number not integer.
Is there any package or function that will allow me to extract the integer?

I tried

```
gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\1",Not_Detect_134$Not_Detect_134)
```

but it return only this

```
[1] "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001"
  [11] "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001"
  [21] "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001"
  [31] "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001"
  [41] "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001" "\001"
```

Comment: `gsub` replaces the matched pattern with the 2nd argument. Are you looking for `grep`?

Comment: `round(readr::parse_number(Not_Detect_134$Not_Detect_134))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:
str_extract(Not_Detect_134, "\d+")